# stop Angular from running the rest of the script and perform another action

Tags: angularjs

I've been working on replacing alert() pop-ups in our Angular code with Angular overlay modals. I'm almost done with the exception of one problem.

I have a modal that opens when the user login has timed out. Some pages will load, fire the script properly and the overlay will be in focus, waiting for the user to click "ok" which sends them to the login page - which is what I want.

On other pages, content will partially load, then fire the overlay modal and for a split second I will see it, then the page continues to load, the modal goes away and even though they get logged out the page doesn't go to the login page.

I need some direction determining what code I should add after the overlay fires to prevent any other code from executing so the user has to interact with the overlay.

I'm sorry I can't share any code - it's proprietary - I just need some direction to go in.

Answer (score 0):

This is very difficult to answer without having access to any code or fully understanding how you are managing various states/views.

A simple solution would be adding a function to the $rootScope which constantly checks if a user is authenticated (aka not timed out).  And then have it perform some action if the user is no longer authenticated.

How you store the authentication indicator is completely up to you.  Without knowing more about the app it would be difficult to say where the best place would be.

Example code:

```
    $rootScope.checkAuth(){
      if (!$sessionStorage.auth){
         $state.go(login)
      }
    }

   setTimeout($rootScope.checkAuth,10000)
```

You could also handle this by not resolving each view/state until a user has been confirmed as authenticated.  Once again, how you set that up would be dependent on the structure of your app.

Comment: I'm researching AngularJS $timeout - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout - to see how to write it to delay the rest of the script from running. So far the problem still persists with a $timeout set at 10000. Thanks, hopefully a resolution is here somewhere.

Comment: sigh... $timeout is undefined... how do I define this within a factory? Any thoughts?

Comment: So I injected $timeout into the factory and now the core Angular file says e is not a function and the $timeout still doesn't work.

Comment: I figured out what was causing the e is not a function but still the timeout won't stop the rest of the script from running. Man Angular is so irritating.

Comment: Sorry, it's just difficult to comment without seeing at least some psuedo code.  Basic angular, you need to inject $timeout, $rootScope (global scope that can be injected and seen by all services), $sessionStorage in my example above.  How are you handling the changing of views/states?